# Outlook email without adjusting column width of pasted Excel range

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that takes a range of cells and pastes it to an Outlook email.

```vb
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)

Dim wdDoc As Word.Document '<=========
Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Emails")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sht.Range("A4:m51").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rng.Copy

With Email
    .To = Sht.Range("C1")
    .Subject = Sht.Range("b1")
    .CC = Sht.Range("H1") & ";" & Sht.Range("H2")
    .Display
     wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting    
End With

Exit Sub
```

I have a longer table, column wise, in the workbook.
When that table is converted into email format it changes the 'Preferred width' to '0.53'.
[image: Outlook Column Width]

As soon as I unclick that radio button it resizes as it should be.

Is there a way to modify the code to not set a preferred width when its pasted into Outlook email?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `wddoc.Range.Tables(1).Columns.AutoFit` at the end

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. For some reason that seemed to have pushed the text closer together. Do you know of a way to turn off autofit entirely? I would rather keep the size of columns from the workbook. Thank you again.